# Error[Pe167]: argument of type "uint16_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *"

Tags: c++, c, iar

I want to establish communication between tablet and stm32 via usb, for which i had added usb libraries in the code. On adding libraries in code i got this error.

Error[Pe167]: argument of type "uint16_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "unsigned char *"

I am using IAR Embedded Workbench EWARM Tool for stm32 coding.Error is comming on return line of function shown below.

```
static USBH_Status USBH_ADK_getProtocol ( USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev, USBH_HOST *phost)
{
phost->Control.setup.b.bmRequestType = USB_D2H | USB_REQ_TYPE_VENDOR | USB_REQ_RECIPIENT_DEVICE;
phost->Control.setup.b.bRequest = ACCESSORY_GET_PROTOCOL;
phost->Control.setup.b.wValue.w = 0;
phost->Control.setup.b.wIndex.w = 0;
phost->Control.setup.b.wLength.w = 2;
 abc= ADK_Machine.protocol;
/* Control Request */
return USBH_CtlReq(pdev, phost, &ADK_Machine.protocol , 2 );
}
```

And the function USBH_CtlReq is

```
USBH_Status USBH_CtlReq     (USB_OTG_CORE_HANDLE *pdev, 
                         USBH_HOST           *phost, 
                         uint8_t             *buff,
                         uint16_t            length)
{
USBH_Status status;
status = USBH_BUSY;

switch (phost->RequestState)
{
case CMD_SEND:
/* Start a SETUP transfer */
USBH_SubmitSetupRequest(phost, buff, length);
phost->RequestState = CMD_WAIT;
status = USBH_BUSY;
break;

case CMD_WAIT:
 if (phost->Control.state == CTRL_COMPLETE ) 
{
  /* Commands successfully sent and Response Received  */       
  phost->RequestState = CMD_SEND;
  phost->Control.state =CTRL_IDLE;  
  status = USBH_OK;      
}
else if  (phost->Control.state == CTRL_ERROR)
{
  /* Failure Mode */
  phost->RequestState = CMD_SEND;
  status = USBH_FAIL;
}   
 else if  (phost->Control.state == CTRL_STALLED )
{
  /* Commands successfully sent and Response Received  */       
  phost->RequestState = CMD_SEND;
  status = USBH_NOT_SUPPORTED;
}
break;

default:
break; 
}
return status;
}
```

can any one please help me in solving this problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You've tagged this as [tag:c#] but it doesn't look like c#.  Is this c++ or c, or something else?  See [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for advice on how to tag.

Comment: I took my best guess as to the correct tags to use.  Please [edit the tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37672/when-should-you-edit-tags) to improve if necessary.

Comment: Please select the correct language, not multiple languages. Also, provide a minimal but complete example, your question as it stands is considered off-topic.

Comment: it doesn't look that the error is in the code you provided.

Comment: What do you need to know more that what the compiler is telling you? You are trying to call a function with the wrong pointer type as an argument. So you have a severe design problem somewhere. Check your types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAICT, in the line:

```
return USBH_CtlReq(pdev, phost, &ADK_Machine.protocol , 2 );
```

the `ADK_Machine.protocol` is an `uint16_t`. If that's true, than, taking its address will yield a `uint16_t *`, which is not convertible to `uint8_t*` that `USBH_CtlReq` expects.

A lot of low-level "sending" functions in C declare arguments as `uint8_t*` or `unsigned char*`, to indicate that they are expecting "bytes". In principle, they could just as well declare `void*`.

But, in this case, the only thing to do is cast, like:

```
return USBH_CtlReq(pdev, phost, (uint8_t*)&ADK_Machine.protocol , 2 );
```

Of course, you need to be mindful that this will not take care of endianness.

Comment: Thanks! Problem was the same as you had observed Error is removed now.

Comment: Is there any compile time settings to avoid this checking i am facing errors for even unsigned char * to uint8_t * argument type.

Comment: @proudengineer That is odd. Can you share the full error reported?

Comment: I have found the solution for the problem. IAR by default has strict type checking and was producing error for mismatch type even enum typecasting to integer were giving error . There is option to convert this errors in warning or suppress it totally. in the c compiler "extra options"